# Platforms added to Gemfile.lock

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, gemfile.lock

I'm trying to track down how a couple platforms were added to my `Gemfile.lock` without explicitly doing so. I must have overlooked these changes when adding new gems but I'm not able to reproduce the same `Gemfile.lock` platform additions when adding those same `Gemfile` changes.

Here is the commit where the new platforms were added.

```
#....
+gem 'sqreen'
+gem 'sanitize'
+

 # Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
 gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
@@ -55,6 +57,8 @@ gem 'postmark-rails'
 group :development, :test do
   # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
   gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
+  gem 'capybara'
+  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
 end
```

And the changes to `Gemfile.lock` in the same commit:

```
 PLATFORMS
+  java
   ruby
+  x64-mingw32
+  x86-mingw32
+  x86-mswin32
```

I tried to reproduce the same modification in a test app but those platforms were not added to the `Gemfile.lock`

I noticed this when recently pushing to heroku:

```
Removing `Gemfile.lock` because it was generated on Windows.
remote:        Bundler will do a full resolve so native gems are handled properly.
remote:        This may result in unexpected gem versions being used in your app.
remote:        In rare occasions Bundler may not be able to resolve your dependencies at all.
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-windows-gemfile
```

I'm not developing on a windows machine and now platform specific gems are being added to `Gemfile.lock` for example:

```
ffi (1.9.18)
ffi (1.9.18-java)
ffi (1.9.18-x64-mingw32)
ffi (1.9.18-x86-mingw32)
```

I'm not entirely sure how the platforms were added. It's not advisable to modify the lock file directly but to appease the heroku warning should I explore removing all platform specific references and remove the non-ruby platforms in my lock file? Any advice here is welcome.

`rails 5.1.3`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

After digging into this with fresh eyes in the morning here's what happened.

I checked my bash history and saw that I ran `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32 x64-mingw32 java` before the commit I posted in the question. This obviously adds more platforms in your `Gemfile.lock` and subsequently platform specific dependencies.

I believe I ran this in the terminal to get rid of what I thought was an error around `tzinfo-data`. More info on that "error" here https://github.com/tzinfo/tzinfo-data/issues/12.

Rather than editing the `Gemfile.lock` directly, I ran `bundle lock --remove-platform x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32 x64-mingw32 java` and this made the appropriate edits to my lock file. More info here http://bundler.io/v1.16/bundle_lock.html.

Heroku no longer throwing an error when deploying as expected. Hope this helps someone in the future.